# choose two prime numbers of length $k$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

Maybe the following is a stupid question, if it is  I apologize, and I encourage you to close my post.

Suppose that I want to encrypt a message with the RSA cryptosystem; the starting rule is the following: take two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ with $p\neq q$ such that, written as bit strings, they both have exactly $k$ digits. Now if the number of digits $k$ is fixed, who ensures that we can find two primes can be represented with $k$ digits? It is reasonable that if $k$ is big then there are always such two numbers, but is there  a formal theorem that says this?

Thanks id advance.

Comment: this might answer your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37378/rsa-creating-a-key-of-desired-length?rq=1

Comment: That there is at least one such prime is a result of "Bertrand's postulate." I'm sure variations of it are proven to prove that there are at least two.

Comment: For example: "In 1976, Lowell Schoenfeld showed that for $n \geq 2010760$, there is always a prime between $n$ and $(1 + 1/16597)n$. This means that there at least $11,000$ primes between $n$ and $2n$ for $n\geq 2010760$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results

Comment: RSA asks for two primes, period. They should be roughly the same size, and not too close, and a few other requirements. But nowhere does it need primes of exactly the same number of digits/bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramanujan showed that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist an $N$ such that for every $n>N$ the numbers of primes between $\displaystyle\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$ is st least $k$, in the specific case for $k=2$ he showed that for every $n\ge11$ there are at least $2$ primes between $\displaystyle\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$.

These numbers are known as Ramanujan's primes ([OEIS A104272](http://oeis.org/A104272))

Answer (score 5):

There is an old theorem called [Betrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) that asserts that there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$ for $n\geq 2$.

There are lots of refinements of this result - it is a fairly minimal one.

[For example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results): "In 1976, Lowell Schoenfeld showed that for $n \geq 2010760$, there is always a prime between $n$ and $(1 + 1/16597)n$ ." This means that there at least $11,000$ primes between $n$ and $2n$ for $n\geq 2010760$.

In reality, there are almost certainly way more primes than this. A crude estimate:

$$\frac{2n}{\log 2n}-\frac{n}{\log n} = \frac{n\log(n/2)}{\log n\log 2n}\approx \frac{n}{\log 2n}$$ when $n$ is in the large range.

Comment: Beautiful, I didn't know even the Bertrand's Postulate.

Comment: I assumed we were talking binary digits - it's even easier to show straight from Betrand if we are talking decimal digits.

Comment: Yes I was thinking at binary digits.

Comment: Using a formula from https://oeis.org/A108954 you can get fairly tight bounds on the number of primes in such an interval. Using your example of n = 2010760, for example, there are between 134,069 and 135,869 primes in (n, 2n).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, no refinement of the Bertrand's postulate is needed. By taking in turn $n=10^k$, $n=2\cdot10^k$ and $n=4\cdot10^k$ you know that there are actually at least 3 primes between $10^k$ and $8\cdot10^k$, all of which have of course $k$ digits.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking binary digits, of course, if we are talking decimal digits, you are correct.

Comment: Well, if you use hexadecimal digits (as I believe most computers do, nowadays) we actually have 4 primes :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a proof here, but the likelihood of an arbitrary integer $n > 1$ being prime is $\dfrac1{\ln n}$ (by the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)).  So over the range of n-bit integers $2^n \le x < 2^{n=1}$, you are overwhelmingly likely to have at least

$$\sum_{2^n \le i < 2^{n+1}} \frac{1}{\ln i} > 2^n\left( \frac{1}{\ln 2^{n+1}} \right) = \frac{2^n}{(n+1)\ln 2}$$ primes.

Comment: Giving you the same answer (up the variable substitution $n\mapsto \log_2n$) as Thomas Andrews. Nice!